# Sorting column in Data table

Tags: apex, visualforce

Is there any native `Apex` solution to get option to sort a column in apex data table?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `apex:dataTable` then you can pre-sort the data in your SOQL query. See here for an example of using apex:dataTable: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_dataTable.htm

Using the query on that page as an example, you could sort it as follows:

```
public List<Account> getAccounts() {
    if(accounts == null)
        accounts = [SELECT name, owner.name FROM account ORDER BY name DESC LIMIT 10];
    return accounts;
}
```

Notice I added the `ORDER BY name DESC` which will then return the results of Accounts by Name in descending order.

Answer (score 2):

The way I've always done this is with dynamic SOQL.  Start with

```
public String sortField = {get;set;}
public String sortDirection {get;set;}
public List<Account> tableContents {get; set;}
public String paramFromPage {get; set;}


private String queryString = 'SELECT Id, Name FROM Account';

public myController(){
    sortField = '';
    sortDirection = '';
    tableContents = Database.query(queryString + sortField + sortDirection);
}
```

Then the header for the `<apex:dataTable/>` column can be a `<apex:commandLink/>` that takes a parameter (like `Name`), assigns it to `sortField`, and sets the `sortDirection`. As in:

VF:

```
<apex:commandLink value="Name">
    <apex:param value="Name" assignTo="{!paramFromPage}"/>
</apex:commandLink>
```

APEX:

```
sortField = String.escapeSingleQuotes(paramFromPage); //to prevent SOQL injection
sortDirection = 'ASC NULLS LAST';
```

If you're interested, you can read more about SOQL injection [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm).

Then if they press the link in the column again, and the new `sortField` is the same as the old `sortField`, then leave it the way it is and change `sortDirection` to `DESC NULLS FIRST` and re-query for `tableContents`.

An added benefit of doing it this way is that you can modify the `dataTable` to support Field Sets without too much additional effort.

Comment: If you don't escape these sort variables, you expose an injection vulnerability.

Comment: Ah, great point.  Added a note about that in my answer.

Comment: Fair enough.  Trying too hard to teach a man to fish, I suppose.  I left the link in there to make myself feel better, but it's part of the actual snippet now.

Comment: I'd +1 but I'm out of votes for the day.

Comment: Don't you have to give the `<apex:param>` tag a `name` attribute for it to actually bind back to the server?

Comment: I think you only need that if you're getting the value from the URL.  The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_param.htm) says that the only required field is `value` and that `assignTo` refers to the setter method that will accept the `value`.

I could be mistaken.

Comment: Thank you Jeff . In my case , I want to sort a number field in a wrapper class List. In that case what would be the way out since I will not be able to use Datbase.query

Comment: In that case, rather than requerying, you can just write your own sort method, and if `sortField` equals the name of the number field, make sure that's the one you're comparing in your sort.  So rather than doing `tableContents = Database.query(...)` you can do `tableContents = sortContents(tableContents)` and reRender the page like before.

Comment: @JeffBennett The escapeSingleQuote does not prevent SOQL injection here. All that function does is prepend a single quote, ' with a backslash \. The purpose of that function is to prevent data breaking out of a *quoted* context. But if the data is never in a quoted context to begin with -- e.g. it is a field or column name, then preventing single quotes does not prevent SOQL injection. What you need to do is validate the provided fields/tables are the ones the user has a right to query, which is complex given your method definition, so I would ask you to rethink this approach.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will show a VF page with two columns in a table :- Account ID and Account Name. Clicking on "Account Name" header in the table will cause sorting of the data in that column. If it is sorted in ascending order, then it will switch to descending order and vice-versa.

```
public class AccountSortHeader
{
    public List<Account> allAcc {get;set;}
    public String sortDirection {get;set;}

    public AccountSortHeader()
    {
        sortDirection = 'asc';
        String query = 'Select Id, name from Account order by Name ' + sortDirection;
        allAcc = Database.query(query);
    }

    public pageReference sortAccNamecolumn()
    {
        if(sortDirection == 'asc')
        {
            sortDirection = 'desc';
        }
        else if(sortDirection == 'desc')
        {
            sortDirection = 'asc';
        }
        String query = 'Select Id, name from Account order by Name ' + sortDirection;
        allAcc = Database.query(query);
        return null;
    }
}
```

VF page :-

```
<apex:page controller="AccountSortHeader">
  <apex:form>
    <apex:pageBlock>
      <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!allAcc}" var="a" id="AccountData">
        <apex:column headerValue="Account ID" value="{!a.Id}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!a.Name}">
          <apex:facet name="header">
          <!-- Any facet whose name is header will apply to the header of this column in the pageBlockTable -->
            <apex:outputPanel>
              <apex:commandLink value="Account Name" action="{!sortAccNamecolumn}" reRender="AccountData"/>
            </apex:outputPanel>
          </apex:facet>
        </apex:column>
      </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```